# Как выявить виртуальные столбцы в таблице?

Tags: sql, oracle

Хочу провести вставку в таблицу, на что мне ругнулось:

ORA-54013: Опервация INSERT для виртуальных столбцов запрещена
ORA-02063: предшествующий line из linkName

Как я понял, виртуальные столбцы - столбцы, которые создаются на лету из других столбцов. Как понять, какие столбцы нужно исключить из вставки?

Comment: Посмотрите в `all_tab_columns`, там наверняка что-нибудь есть на эту тему. А если у вас есть нормальная IDE, смотрите сразу DDL скрипт создания таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посмотреть в системном словаре, например так:

```
create table tst1 (id number);
alter table TST1 add v_id as (id*2);

select t.column_name, 
       t.VIRTUAL_COLUMN 
from   all_tab_cols t 
where  t.TABLE_NAME = 'TST1' 
and    t.VIRTUAL_COLUMN = 'YES'
```

Или в вашей ИДЕ можно посмотреть. Скорее всего там должны отображаться схематичное строение таблицы или скрипты DDL.

Comment: А как можно произвести вставк, минуя эти значения? Предположим, у меня вставка: `INSERT INTO TST2 SELECT COL1, COL2, VIRTUAL_COL3, COL4 FROM SOME_TABLE;` И вот убрать бы теперь виртуальный третий столбец. Но без него ругается, что недостаточно значений, а с ним, что нельзя инсертить в виртуальный столбец

Comment: Можно попробовать явно перечислить колонки, в которые вставляешь значения

Comment: да так и сделал, но так не круто вообще

Comment: Почему не круто? Наоборот, круто. Если структура таблицы изменится по каким то причинам, старый код продолжит работать корректно.

Comment: Потому что там больше сотни колонок - умотаешься перечислять х_х Ну да ладно. Скрипт тогда экселем прост дорисовал.

Comment: Для написания запросов использую PLSQL Developer. По горячей клавише дополняет все колонки.

Comment: Я тоже использую девелопер. Похоже, я просто был не в курсе об этой фиче.